# Custom Model for TableView or QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a TableView with two columns:

- The first one for a parameter name
- The second one with the parameter value, which could be a float, bool, int or a string

The second column should be editable, and a bool should be represented by a checkbox. For this model, should I subclass QAbstractItemModel or would the QStandardItemModel be fitting? Also, should one item have the two properties name and value, or should this be better seperated into two items?

Comment: This question is rather broad, and doesn't identify any issues you have with either one. You should narrow it down, specifying why you think one or the other might (not) be fitting, and what failed when you tried.

Comment: To both questions, anyone, try, experiment, analyze. We solve concrete problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your subject field. If you have big number of parameters then you should subclass QAbstractItemModel, because in the other case time of data view will be significant, if not QStandardItemModel is quite simple for this purpose.