# Getting type of QStandardItem in Qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QStandardItemModel which I display using a TableView in qml. It uses QVariant to store the data. I want to have custom delegates depending on which type the stored data has, e.g. like this

```
    Component {
        id: myDelegate
        Loader {
            property var roleTwo: model.two
            sourceComponent: if( CODE_FOR_MY_ITEM_HAS_BOOL_TYPE) {
                                 checkBoxDelegate}
                             else { stringDelegate}
        }
    }
```

However, I don't know how to check the type of an item in my model. How can this be achieved?

Upon request, I provide more context to this question:

As posted here [Custom Model for TableView or QStandardItemModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389489/custom-model-for-tableview-or-qstandarditemmodel) I want to have a TableView with two columns, a parameter name and a parameter value. The goal is to have a list of editable parameters which control the behaviour of an algorithm. For this, I use a QStandardItemModel defined like this:

```
class mystandardmodel: public QStandardItemModel
{

public:
    mystandardmodel();
    enum Role {
         role1=Qt::UserRole,
         role2
     };

     explicit mystandardmodel(QObject * parent = 0): QStandardItemModel(parent){}
     //explicit mystandardmodel( int rows, int columns, QObject * parent = 0 )
     //    : QStandardItemModel(rows, columns, parent){}

     QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const{
          QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
          roles[role1] = "one";
          roles[role2] = "two";
          return roles;
 }
};
```

This model right now is displayed like this:

```
TableView {
    id: tableView2
    x: 69
    y: 316
    width: 318
    height: 150
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Parameter Name"
        role: "one"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Value"
        role: "two"
        delegate: myDelegate
    }
    model: myTestModel
}

Component {
    id: myDelegate
    Loader {
        property var roleTwo: model.two
        sourceComponent: if(typeof(roleTwo)=='boolean') {
                             checkBoxDelegate}
                         else { stringDelegate}
    }
}

Component {
    id: checkBoxDelegate
    CheckBox{text: roleTwo}
}

Component {
    id: stringDelegate
    Text {text: roleTwo

    }
}
```

So is this the way you would do it? Also, I am happy for hints on who to make the model editable.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think the question is specific and easy enough so that a MCVE does not help

Comment: One way would be to use javascript:
    if(typeof(roleTwo)=='boolean')
but I was wondering whether there is a Qt way

Comment: is that I find it strange that you use a QStandardItemModel to populate a TableView, TableView uses the roles to access the data but in QStandardItemModel you can not create roles, besides my idea is to add a new role that indicates the type of data, a Boolean QVariant can convert to other types of data as string, int, etc. I want to be clear about how you are doing with your progress, so I require a [mcve], personally I would use a QAbstractListModel.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question. As you see, I use a QStandardItemModel with roles, but I am happy to use the AbstractList Model if it offers advantages.

Comment: checking I think your option is the best, that is typeof if you are going to discriminate between booleans and strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `typeof()` works for your use-case, then you can roll with it.

What I personally like to do is have an integer member to denote the particular type. This has an array of advantages, here are some:

- you can use the same underlying data type to drive different gui types, for example, a string might be a name or an info, one might be editable, the other read only
- it works in cases where you might have fundamentally different model items with fundamentally different sets of data
- you can use it as an index, and have an array of `Component`s, and in the loader simply use `sourceComponent: guitypes[type]`

Comment: A question: If you say you have an integer member, for a c++ model would that mean having a dedicated role for that? Because I was wondering whether there is an easy way to use members of my model class for the roles...

Comment: Is there a way to do it without roles?

Comment: You can use a function exposed to QML that returns the integer type for a model item.